# UITabbar disappear when pushing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

i'm having trouble with a navigation Controller, when i'm pushing my view controller to an xib a see a UITabbar but in mij xib where i'm pushing the view to i'm doing this to push the xib where i'm pushing to, to another file but when i use this line of code the UITabbar doesn't show up.

What i'm doing in view controller 1 i check if a JSON file contains 0,1 or 2 items when it's for example '1' item in the JSON i would like to push the view controller to a file special for the '2 item file' i'm pushing on this way:

```
   UIViewController *rootController = 
    [[2ViewController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:@"2ViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But when i do that the UITabbar disappear 'under' the view controller. Could somebody help me out solving this problem please?

Answer (score -1):

you set set navigationController  into UITabBarController.

Like
    //Add to tabbars.
    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, nil];

```
myTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Comment: [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
It should window contains TabBarController.view contains navigationController. 

And I didn't see how you add tab bar in your code.